# Alternative to extending two Activities (not allowed)

Tags: java, android

Recently I learned about android services and I decided to use them.

First I just made one Service in order to handle bluetooth connectivity. I also coded an abstracty Activity in order to handle binding to this service so I don't have to repeate that code every time I want to bind the service to an Activity.

Now here comes my problem. I started to code a second service to handle api rest calls (you may think I don't need to have this in a service, but I want to be able to make api calls even when my application is closed).

So thats what I have:

- 2 Services
- 2 abstract activities to handle binding to each service
- Some activities that needs to inherit binding functionality but cannot extend the both classes.

For now, the only thing I think I can do is to write another activity that handles both service bindings (but if possible I would like to not do that to keep code separated)

Comment: You would not need a bound service in either of these scenarios. Even if you elect to go with bound services, you do not need an abstract activity class to reuse binding logic. For example, you could have an `AndroidViewModel` manage the binding.

Comment: @CommonsWare never used it, but I wil try.